# How to download a file from S3 using "Version ID"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file in S3 with multiple `Version ID` and when i do a 's3Client.getObject("bucketName","Key")' using Java it gives me the latest file only. But i need all the files of a given key.

Is there a straight forward way to do this in JAVA ?

As i was not able to find an answer i am trying this way. First fetch the list of `Version ID` and then iterate them to download the file.

Now, I have a list of `Version ID` and complete `Object URL`. Is there a way to download files using these two ?

Similar question - [How to read a s3 file for all versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563179/how-to-read-a-s3-file-for-all-versions)

Comment: Which version of the AWS Java SDK are you using?

Comment: @Jacob G. - Not sure. How do I find that ?

Comment: Check the import of `S3Client`. If it begins with `com.amazonaws`, then you're using v1 of the SDK. If it begins with `software.amazon`, then you're using v2.

Comment: There are numerous variants of `GetObject`. One of them accepts a `GetObjectRequest` and if you look at the docs for that class, you'll see `GetObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, String versionId)`.

Comment: @Jacob G. Yes you are right I am using version 1.

Comment: @jarmond - Yes I already went through the docs and what you say is there. Can you please give me a working sample ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in the comments, using version 1 of the SDK you can use the below code to download files with version ids:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .build();
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key, versionId);
S3Object object = s3.getObject(request);
```

You can also optionally close the client using `s3.shutdown();` but you need to do it after you are done with the file. Otherwise, it would close the connection and cause an exception (for example if you are reading or streaming a file from S3).